# How to remove commas from numeric values in a string with other commas?

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I am working with an array that contains account statement. I want to be able to remove commas from numeric values in order to be able to explode with comma without loosing vital values.

For example, my array contains indexes like:

```
26 => 20/08/2099,"ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL (ON-US) ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL (ON-US) EMPEMOM, LAGA ATM 2 LOGO NG 000360585490","",20/08/2018,"5,000","","1,316.01"

27 => 27/08/2027,BANK CHARGE 26 SMS CHARGE AND VAT FOR 27TH JUL - 23RD AUG 2018,2803064 028,27/08/2018,109.2,"","1,206.81"
```

I want to remove the comma in "5,000" and other monetary values without removing the commas between each strings, so that the output will look like:

```
26 => 20/08/2099,"ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL (ON-US) ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL (ON-US) EMPEMOM, LAGA ATM 2 LOGO NG 000360585490","",20/08/2018,"5000","","1316.01"

27 => 27/08/2027,BANK CHARGE 26 SMS CHARGE AND VAT FOR 27TH JUL - 23RD AUG 2018,2803064 028,27/08/2018,109.2,"","1206.81"
```

Comment: If you do an explode, the commas between quotes are not gonna be separators.

Comment: The source data is poorly formed. Where is it coming from and are there options to get it in a different format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and as the pattern you could use:

```
"\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+\.\d{2}"
```

- `"\d{1,3}` Match `"` followed by 1-3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})!` Repeat 1+ times matching a comma and 3 digits
- `\.\d{2}"` Match a dot and 2 digits followed by `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWesOr/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/NXA98)

In the callback of `preg_replace_callback` replace the comma with an empty string and return the match.

For example:

```
$atm = array(
    '26' => '20/08/2099,"ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL (ON-US) ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL (ON-US) EMPEMOM, LAGA ATM 2 LOGO NG 000360585490","",20/08/2018,"5,000","","1,316.01"',
    '27' => '27/08/2027,BANK CHARGE 26 SMS CHARGE AND VAT FOR 27TH JUL - 23RD AUG 2018,2803064 028,27/08/2018,109.2,"","1,206.81"'
);

$atm = array_map(function($x) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/"\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+\.\d{2}"/', function($m) {
       return  str_replace(',', '', $m[0]);
    }, $x);
}, $atm);

print_r($atm);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [26] => 20/08/2099,"ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL (ON-US) ATM CASH WITHDRAWAL (ON-US) EMPEMOM, LAGA ATM 2 LOGO NG 000360585490","",20/08/2018,"5,000","","1316.01"
    [27] => 27/08/2027,BANK CHARGE 26 SMS CHARGE AND VAT FOR 27TH JUL - 23RD AUG 2018,2803064 028,27/08/2018,109.2,"","1206.81"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach your array and explode by comma then replace "," every array then check if it is number or not

foreach array then explode string by comma

```
$stringArray=explode(",",$str)
```

then replace "," every $stringArray

```
$CheckNumber= str_replace(',', '', $string);
```

and check if it is number by:

```
if (is_numeric($CheckNumber))
   $stringArray[i]=$CheckNumber;
```

at the end join array

```
join(",",$stringArray);
```